# i want to set a navigation drawer in android activity but its not working,

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I have to implement navigation drawer in my app activity but its not working.It is showing button for the drawer but its not responding.

Here is my code:

```
// ListView represents Navigation Drawer
private ListView mDrawerList;
private String[] drawerlist = { "Submit Task", "Edit Profile", "Log Out" };

// ActionBarDrawerToggle indicates the presence of Navigation Drawer in the
// action bar
private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
private ViewPager viewPager;
private TabsPagerAdapter mAdapter;
private ActionBar actionBar;

// Tab titles
private String[] tabs = { "My profile", "Friend's posts", "Friend List",
        "Top posts" };

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_homepage);
    // Initilization
    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    actionBar = getActionBar();
    mAdapter = new TabsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    viewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
    getActionBar().setTitle("OTAKU");

    // Getting reference to the DrawerLayout
    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

    mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.drawer_list);

    // Getting reference to the ActionBarDrawerToggle
    mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
            R.drawable.ic_drawer, R.string.drawer_open,
            R.string.drawer_close) {

        /** Called when drawer is closed */
        public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
            getActionBar().setTitle("OTAKU");

            invalidateOptionsMenu();

        }

        /** Called when a drawer is opened */
        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            getActionBar().setTitle("OTAKU");
            invalidateOptionsMenu();
        }

    };

    // Setting DrawerToggle on DrawerLayout
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

    // Creating an ArrayAdapter to add items to the listview mDrawerList
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            R.layout.drawer_list_item, drawerlist);

    // Setting the adapter on mDrawerList
    mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);

    // Enabling Home button
    getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

    // Enabling Up navigation
    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    // Setting item click listener for the listview mDrawerList
    mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
        }
    });
    // Adding Tabs
    for (String tab_name : tabs) {
        actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(tab_name)
                .setTabListener(this));
    }

    viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            // on changing the page
            // make respected tab selected
            actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mDrawerToggle.syncState();
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item))
        return true;
    if (item.getItemId() == R.id.action_search) {

        Intent j = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Searchresults.class);
        startActivity(j);

        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

/** Called whenever we call invalidateOptionsMenu() */
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // If the drawer is open, hide action items related to the content view
    boolean drawerOpen = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList);

    menu.findItem(R.id.action_search).setVisible(!drawerOpen);
    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}

public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.mainmenu1, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
}

@Override
public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

I have doubts regarding onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) method.
Here is layout file

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <!-- The main content view -->

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    <!-- The navigation drawer -->

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/drawer_list"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="#111"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp" />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your onOptionsItemSelected method you aren't doing anything when the user clicks on your drawerToggle. You need to add code to open/close the drawer.

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item))
    // code to open/close drawer here
    return true;
if (item.getItemId() == R.id.action_search) {

    Intent j = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Searchresults.class);
    startActivity(j);

    return true;
}
return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Comment: did you add a clicklistener to the drawer toggle in your other app?

Comment: https://github.com/javatechig/AndroidNavigationDrawer/blob/master/src/com/javatechig/drawer/MainActivity.java

Comment: actually this is the refrence from where i took the code and its working but not mine